# Macでサクラエディタを使用したい。

Tags: macos, サクラエディタ

MacBookPro2016 バージョン10.12.7　を使用しております。サクラエディタを使用したく、https://tech-camp.in/note/952/　このサイトを見ながら進めておりました。EasyWineのDLは無事完了しましたが、サクラエディタのDL後に解凍しようとすると　「エラーコード 2
"p7zip"を使用中に回復不可能なエラーが起きました」と出てしまいます。どのようにすれば良いでしょうか。ちなみに解凍アプリはkekaです。

Answer (score 1):

もしかしたら、このエラーなのかもしれません。
https://github.com/aonez/Keka/issues/18

他の解凍アプリで試してみるほうが早いかも。

Comment: 遅くなり申し訳ありません。ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Answer (score 0):

リンク先の注意書きは非常に甘い物ですので普通に使えると誤解されているのかもしれませんが、エミュレータを使ってWindowsアプリをMacで使うというのは、実際には技術的にも法的にも簡単なことではありません。

MacとWindows両方に十分な経験がありトラブルは自力で解決できそれを乗り越えてでも使いたいという強い動機があれば別ですが、そうでなければMac OSネイティブで動くテキストエディタがありますのでそちらを使ってください。(Mac テキストエディタなどで検索してみるといろいろ見つかります)

WindowsとMacで環境を出来るだけそろえたいということだとしても、Windows Mac両方で動く物もありますのでそういった物を検討してください。

(なお、お勧めのエディタを教えてください、という質問はまず間違いなくクローズされますのでしないでください)

Comment: 遅くなり申し訳ありません。検討してみます、ありがとうございます。